# fmincon doesn't find a global minimum for a convex function

Tags: matlab, newtons-method, convex-optimization

In my opinion, `fmincon` is a built-in function for local minimum in matlab. If the objective function is a convex problem, there is only one basin and the local minimum is the global minimum. While starting from different initial points in my experiment, the algorithm got different minimums function. I wonder if `fmincon` guarantees to be converged to a global minimum for convex problem. If not, is there any other techiniques I can use for convex opimization as fast as possible? Thanks.

P.S. `fmincon` use `interior-point-method` for searching minimum in default. Is this a normal problem for `interior-point method`, that is ,starting from different intial point, the method can get different global minimum for convex problem?

EDIT:

The objective is to minimize the sum of energy consumption by a group of users in a communication process, while the allocation of bandwidth is search. The transmission rate is

```
$r_k = x_k * log_2(1+\frac{g_k*p_k}{x_k})$
```

The optimization problem is as follow

```
$min_{x} sum_k \frac{p_k*b_k}{r_k}$
s.t. $sum_k x_k \leq X_{max}$
```

The objective and constraints are all convex, thus this should be a convex optimization problem.

For programming code, it is just as follow,

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon');
problem.options = options;
problem.solver = 'fmincon';
problem.objective = @(x) langBW(x, in_s, in_e, C1, a, p_ul);
problem.Aineq = ones(1,user_num);
problem.bineq = BW2;
problem.nonlcon = @(x) nonlConstr_bw(x,a,p_ul,T1,in_s,in_e,BW2);

problem.x0 = ones(user_num,1)
[b_ul,fval] = fmincon(problem);
```

`langBW` is the objective function, which is a convex function of `x`, the code of `langBW` is as follow,

```
function fmin = langBW(x, in_s, in_e, C1, a, p_ul)
if size(x,1)<size(x,2)
    x = x';
end
b_ul = x;
r_ul = b_ul .* log2(1 + a.*p_ul./b_ul);

fmin = sum((in_s+in_e).*p_ul./r_ul) + sum(C1);

end
```

The `nonlConstr_bw` is the function of nonlinear constraints. It is shown as follow,

```
function [c,ceq] = nonlConstr_bw(x,a,p_ul,T1,in_s,in_e)
user_num = size(p_ul,1);
if size(x,1)<size(x,2)
    x = x';
end
b_ul = x;
r_ul = b_ul .* log2(1 + a.*p_ul./b_ul);

c1 = max(in_s./r_ul) + in_e./r_ul - T1;
c = c1;
ceq = zeros(user_num,1);

end
```

Except `x`, all other variables are supplied. The problem is that when I set different `problem.x0`, for example, when `problem.x0=ones(user_num,1);`, the solution of `[b_ul,fval] = fmincon(problem);` is different from that when `problem.x0=2*ones(user_num,1);`. That is what I am confused about.

Comment: You should post some specific information, preferably code if you want something better than a guess.

Comment: @MadPhysicist hi, thanks for your advice. Just edit my post with the optimization problem.

Comment: Are you sure your function is convex? If not, the whole discussion is pointless.

Comment: @AndreaCassioli The only variables is x, which is in denominator. I calculate the second-order derives and got positive value.

Comment: OK, does fmincon really converge? any warnings, errors? And what do you mean that you find different optimal values? Small fluctuation may occur if your problem is ill-conditioned...

Comment: BTW, I guess convexity would depend on the coefficients you choose and the region you look at. Just tried to plot it and it may not be convex at all.

Comment: This still does not show how you implemented your optimization. SO is a site to help with coding, and it is difficult to tell what the problem is without seeing code. Also, if you want to use LaTeX formatting, please read this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164286/346663. There are others, but I can't seem to find them ATM.

Comment: @AndreaCassioli No warnings and errors, the exitflag returns 1 and a local minimum is found. For fmincon function, you need to supply an initial point of  _x0_ . From my experiments, derived from different _x0_ , the final local minimum is different and the final minimal value is different.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your advice. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

`fmincon` uses the [following algorithms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-the-algorithm.html):

```
'interior-point' (default)
'trust-region-reflective'
'sqp' (Sequential Quadratic Programming)
'sqp-legacy'
'active-set'
```

These methods will converge to a local minimia but not necessarily a global minimum. Further minima may not be unique. The only way to guarantee a global minima is to search the whole solution space.

From your comment, there appears to be only a signal minima? (For example, a shifted parabola?) Then it should converge.

edit--

Even if your function appears convex, the constraints can lead [to multiple local minima](https://www.lindo.com/doc/online_help/lingo15_0/convexity.htm). Sometimes this is called a "loosely" convex function

[image]

Comment: Yes, I updated my post for interior-point method. While I still wonder, for convex objective function, there should be only one local minimum, then it is the global minimum. It shouldn't be related to what initial point you choose. However, based on different initial points, the minumum points are also different, and the same for minimal value. Is this a normal problem for convex optimization? If not, is there any way to elaborate this?

Comment: @user3919259 So, you also have those KKT conditions right? Take look at whats called "loosely convex" https://www.lindo.com/doc/online_help/lingo15_0/convexity.htm

Comment: @user3919259 Also there is a reasonable chance that your function isn't actually convex...

Comment: Thanks a lot. For a loosely convex function as you mentioned, the optimal value should be the same. However, from my problem, starting from different intial $x_0$, the minimal values are different. I have just updated the specifice information of my problem, maybe we can figure out more on this.